# Why won't guard allow the router to activate after HTTP request?

Tags: angular, angular8

I have a guard that either returns Observable or will route to another url based on the HTTP response.  The service the guard is calling will either make the HTTP call or if it has already been called and is saved in the service, it should return the stored value.  See the service below.  Without the if statement, everything works fine, but with the if statement, it seems the guard doesn't allow the router to activate(the map return true).  There's no error in the console.  Thanks in advance.

Edit: Using Angular 8.1

Service:

```
private company: Company;
public companySubject: BehaviorSubject<Company> = new BehaviorSubject(this.company);

get(slug: string, params: HttpParams = null): Observable<Company>
  {
    if (this.company && this.company.slug === slug) {
      this.companySubject.next(this.company);
      return this.companySubject.asObservable();
    }

    return this.http.get<Company>(`companies/${slug}`, {params: params}).pipe(
      tap((response: Company) => {
        this.company = response;
        this.companySubject.next(this.company);
      })
    );
  }
```

Guard:

```
    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean>
  {
    const slug = route.parent.paramMap.get('company');

    return this.companyService.get(slug).pipe(
      tap((company: Company) => {
        if (
          company.locations_count == 0 ||
          !company.subscribed
        ) {
          this.router.navigateByUrl(`/app/company/${slug}/setup`);
        }
      }),
      map(() => true)
    );
  }
```

Comment: Hello, which angular version are you using ?

Comment: @Soukyone Angular 8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it in a simpler way:

```
private company: Company;

get(slug: string, params: HttpParams = null): Observable<Company>
{
  if (this.company && this.company.slug === slug) {
    return of(this.company);
  }

   return this.http.get<Company>(`companies/${slug}`, {params: params}).pipe(
      tap((response: Company) => {
        this.company = response;
       }),
       map(res => res)
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Yeah, it seems return this.companySubject.asObservable(); was what was breaking it.  Changing it to return of(this.company); made it work.